# how to get the marker coordinates from geoObjectCollection Yandex.Map

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps

There is a collection of objects displayed on the map. There is an event on the click of the label. How to determine the coordinates of the label that was clicked?
`.get('coords)` will not work, you need to get exactly the coordinates prescribed in the collection, but how can I not understand, I tried `.getCoordinates()`, but I did not understand how to prescribe correctly, or do something else here...

```
var myGeoObject = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection(
   {
    preset: 'islands#blueIcon'
});
for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
    myGeoObject.add(new ymaps.Placemark(coords[i]));
}
myMap.geoObjects.add(myGeoObject);

myGeoObject.events.add('click', function (e) {
        
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myGeoObject.events.add('click', function (e) {
        var click_coord = e.get('target').geometry.getCoordinates();
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).